# EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396) when connecting to odoo 15

Tags: python, ssl, odoo

I am running a django app that connects to an Odoo instance. Like so

```
userlog = request.user
if request.method == 'GET':
    
    # return render(request, 'inventory_updates.html')
    
    products = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.product', 'search_read', [[['type', 'in', ['product', 'consu']]]], …
    {'fields': ['name']})
    
     
    return render(request, 'inventory_updates.html', {'products': products})
```

For some reason during certain times when making a get request(and by default searching/connecting to odoo) to the Django view this error pops up

```
EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)
```

Here is how I am connecting to the server.

```
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url),allow_none=True,verbose=False, use_datetime=True,context=ssl._create_unverified_context())


common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url),allow_none=True,verbose=False, use_datetime=True,context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
```

The server is ubuntu 20, running Nginx, and both apps are hosted on the same server. The root issue I belive is due to the SSL being self-signed. But I can't figure out why the issue only happens sometimes and not consitently.

I have checked the python tls version, checked tls for the nginx cofig files.